# find usage with -L

Tags: find, symlink

I have

```
link -> file
```

I do

```
find -L . -name 'link'
```

And get

```
./link
```

Why is that?

man find says:

-L   :  Follow  symbolic  links.   When find examines or prints information about files, the information used shall be
              taken from the properties of the file to which the link points, not from the link itself (unless it is a  bro‐
              ken symbolic link or find is unable to examine the file to which the link points).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With `-L`, it examines the *properties* of the file - contents or metadata, not those of the link. E.g. if you use `-atime`, it will check the `atime` of the file, not the link:

```
$ find testdir/ -name link -newer testdir/ref
testdir/link
$ find -L testdir/ -name link -newer testdir/ref
$
```

`testdir/link` was created after `testdir/ref`, but the file it points at was not.

Comment: Can you explain taking my example? What I understand is this: In my example find starts its search. It encounters ./link, since -L is in effect it dereferences it and takes the properties of ./file. It compares name of ./file with pattern 'link' and since it does not match, should not report any o/p. Whats wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: From the find manual you quoted, "the information used shall be taken from the properties of the file to which the link points." The name of a file is not one of its properties, so it still uses the name of the link. That's also a great deal more useful than the name of the real file.

Comment: "The name of the file is not one of its properties" I did not know that. Any such other attributes of files which are not considered properties? To be honest I am still skeptical and would wait what others have to say.

Comment: Same as @abc, didn't know that a file name isn't a file property. Where can I find this piece of information in any documentation and/or man page(s)?
Please refer to where I can learn more about a file properties.

Comment: @joker the properties of the file are the ones returned by `stat(2)` call. In UN*Xoids, a file can have _0_, _1_, or more names (AKA _directory entries_). While most common situation is usually 1 name (_link_/_hardlink_ - do not confuse with _symlink_) per regular file (for directories link count it is usually _2_ or _3_), one can create/add names (_links_) to the same file using `link(2)` and `unlink(2)` syscalls - either programmatically, or via `ln(1)` (without `-s` param!) and `rm(1)` commands. Number of _links_ (names) is also what is displayed by popular `ls -l` command in second column.

Answer (score 50):

The general rule is that if a command operates on links (i.e. directory entries, which are pointers to inodes) then the command treats symlinks as themselves rather than as the object the link points to.  Otherwise the command operates on what the symlink points to.  Thus `cp` follows symlinks by default and copies the contents of the file pointed to by the link.  But when you ask `cp` to deal with directory entries by specifying `-R`, it stops following symlinks.  `mv` always works with directory entries, and so it never follows symlinks.

The `find` command's normal activity is to operate on directory entries, so symlinks are not followed by default.  Adding `-L` causes `find` to follow symlinks for all properties *except* the one that cannot be ignored when doing directory search, the name.  One of purposes of `find -name` is to provide input for commands like `mv` and `rm`, which operate on directory entries.  There would be unpleasant and surprising results if `find -L dir -name` could produce names that pointed outside the directory tree rooted at `dir`.

Comment: WOW! Why is this subtle concept not well illustrated on man pages (unless I missed it)? This is a big surprise for me.

Comment: @Kyle Jones `There would be unpleasant and surprising results if `find -L dir -name` could produce names that pointed outside the directory tree rooted at dir.` => shouldn't that be: there would be unpleasant ... if  `find dir -name pattern` ... ? because adding -L allows pointing to outside dir

Comment: So how to get  `cp -R` to copy stuff under a symlink?

Comment: @StephenBoesch use "rsync" instead of "cp".  It's always better.