# Show contents of symbolic link

Tags: zsh, ls, symlink

In `zsh`, I make a symbolic link

```
$ ln -s ~/Documents symboliclink
```

and then I want to know what's inside this symbolic link.

```
$ ls -l symboliclink
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 21 Oct 10 15:56 symboliclink -> /home/user/Documents
```

This shows only the symbolic link, not what's inside it. If i use `ls` only, it lists the contents, but if I used the `-l` flag, it doesn't. This works in `bash` both for `ls` and `ls -l`. How can I get that behavior in `zsh` as well?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I received 4 excellent answers and I had to pick one as a solution. If I could, I would pick all 4 as solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One likely cause for the seeming difference in the output of `ls -l` between *zsh* and *bash* is the use of `Tab`-completion with `AUTO_REMOVE_SLASH` enabled in *zsh* (which is the default).

> **AUTO_REMOVE_SLASH** <D>
>
> When  the  last  character  resulting from a completion is a slash and the next character typed is a word delimiter, a slash, or a character that ends a command (such as a semicolon or an ampersand), remove the slash.

When typing `ls -l symb`<kbd>Tab</kbd>, both `zsh` and `bash` will complete this to `ls -l symboliclink/` (note the `/` at the end). The difference is that `zsh` (with enabled `AUTO_REMOVE_SLASH`) will remove the slash, if you just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (i.e. end the command) there.

So you will effectively run `ls -l symboliclink/` in *bash*, which tells `ls -l` to look behind the link. But in *zsh* you will run `ls -l symboliclink`, which tells `ls -l` that you want to see the information about the link and not the target directory.

`ls` without option `-l` will always show the contents of the target directory, regardless of there being an `/` at the end or not.

---

In order to get *zsh* to not remove the slash at the end, it is sufficient to just type it explicitly after `TAB`-completion. Usually this will not visibly change the completed text, but if you type a space or confirm the command, the `/` will remain. "Usually" because it is possible to set a highlighting for automatically added suffix characters, for example magenta and bold:

```
zle_highlight[(r)suffix:*]="suffix:fg=magenta,bold"
```

(**Note:** this may not work when using the external [ZSH Syntax Highlighting plugin](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting))

Another solution is (obviously) to disable `AUTO_REMOVE_SLASH`. This can be done with

```
setopt noautoremoveslash
```

Answer (score 10):

This is `ls` option `-H`:

```
ls -lH  symboliclink
```

From `man 1p ls`:

> -H
>
> If a symbolic link referencing a file of type directory is specified on the command line, ls shall evaluate the file information and  file  type  to  be
>                 those  of  the  file referenced by the link, and not the link itself; however, ls shall write the name of the link itself and not the file referenced by
>                 the link.

Also note option -L

> -L
>
> Evaluate the file information and file type for all symbolic links (whether named on the command line or encountered in a file hierarchy) to be those of the  file  referenced by the link, and not the link itself; however, ls shall write the name of the link itself and not the file referenced by the link. When -L is used with -l, write the contents of symbolic links in the long format (see the STDOUT section).

Answer (score 6):

Simply add a '/' at the end.

```
ls -l symboliclink/
```

Comment: I'm curious if that is documented somewhere or just behavior you noticed?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of the `ls` program does not depend on the shell that calls it. If you observe different behavior with `ls` in bash and in zsh, it's because you have an alias (or function) called `ls` in one of the shells but not in the other. The behavior you're observing in zsh corresponds to what `ls` does, so you must be calling it with additional options in bash.

You may have aliased `ls` to `ls -H` or `ls -L`, to make it dereference symbolic links. This is a bad idea because you then can't get information about the symlinks themselves, other than by bypassing the alias (`\ls`).

When a file is a symbolic link to a directory, you can act on the directory rather than the file by adding a slash at the end: `ls -l symboliclink/` is equivalent to `ls -l symboliclink/.`. See [When is a symlink treated as the thing it links to, and as a symlink?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161929/when-is-a-symlink-treated-as-the-thing-it-links-to-and-as-a-symlink)

Comment: Though your observations are correct, I do not have an alias set. The difference is that when I do `ll symbol` and then hit `Tab`, `bash` autocompletes to `ll symboliclink/`, while `zsh` autocompletes to `ll symboliclink`. Thanks for the clarifications, though. +1