# Effect of slash (/) suffixes on symlink names for `ls` with the `-F` option

Tags: ls, symlink, options, slash

By way of example, I have a directory structure like this:

```
$ \ls -F
dir/  lnk@

$ \ls -F dir
FILE

$ \ls -l lnk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group d Mon hh:mm lnk -> dir
```

My `ls` command is aliased. I am using `\ls` to get standard behavior (I think).

### The question is

When using the `-F` option with `ls`, why does appending a slash to the symlink name affect the behavior of `ls`?

```
$ \ls -F lnk
lnk@

\ls -F lnk/
FILE
```

Without the `/`, the symlink itself is listed with an `@` indicator/flag/classifier; with the `/`, the files in the directory that the symlink references are listed with indicators (`FILE` is a regular file).

I'm not sure whether to call the behavior with no options consistent or inconsistent:

```
$ \ls lnk
FILE

\ls lnk/
FILE
```

I am not finding an explanation for this in `man ls`.

### Similar Posts

[Using ls command with symbolic links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425029/using-ls-command-with-symbolic-links)

[Show contents of symbolic link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315461/show-contents-of-symbolic-link)

### References

[Trailing slashes on symbolic links to directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29769/trailing-slashes-on-symbolic-links-to-directories)

The IEEE and the Open Group (2004) "Pathname Resolution" [subsection 4.11](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) in *The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6*

The IEEE and the Open Group (2018a) "Pathname Resolution" [subsection 4.13](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html) in *The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7*

The IEEE and the Open Group (2018b) "[ls](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html)"

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski RE "Trailing slashes on..." yes, partially.

Comment: The texts you quote under "Postscript" seem to tell the answer. You could post those as an actual answer below.

Comment: @ilkkachu Re "...post those as an actual answer...": DONE.

Answer (score 2):

In short, because `lnk` and `lnk/` refer to different files.

### The Long Answer

After reviewing IEEE and The Open Group (2018a), It seems my question misunderstood pathname resolution. In particular: 1) `lnk/` is equivalent to `lnk/.` Therefore `lnk` and `lnk/` name different files.

> If a symbolic link is encountered during pathname resolution, the behavior shall depend on whether the pathname component is at the end of the pathname and on the function being performed.

Although I do not find the behavior of `\ls -F lnk` or `\ls lnk` specified in the man page, I do find it in The IEEE and the Open Group (2018b):

> If one or more of the -d, -F, or -l options are specified, and neither the -H nor the -L option is specified, for each operand that names a file of type symbolic link to a directory, ls shall write the name of the file as well as any requested, associated information. If none of the -d, -F, or -l options are specified, or the -H or -L options are specified, for each operand that names a file of type symbolic link to a directory, ls shall write the names of files contained within the directory as well as any requested, associated information.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know the official answer, but:

- There is a name "lnk" in the directory. I do not know what that is.
- `ls -F lnk` - Show me a type of that name
- `ls -F lnk/` - Here is a path, show me all files in the specified path, with type marks
- `ls lnk/` - Here is a path, show me all files in the specified path
- `ls lnk` - I allow OS to determine what that file is and asking to show the most logical info for it

Please note: I do not care in this case is it a link or not. I am thinking in terms of "name" and "path" only.