# find and symbolic link

Tags: linux, command-line, find, symlink

I was skimming over the documentation of find to better utilize the command usage.

I was reading the part that says

> GNU find will handle symbolic links in one of two ways; firstly, it
>   can dereference the links for you - this means that if it comes across
>   a symbolic link, it examines the file that the link points to, in
>   order to see if it matches the criteria you have specified. Secondly,
>   it can check the link itself in case you might be looking for the
>   actual link. If the file that the symbolic link points to is also
>   within the directory hierarchy you are searching with the find
>   command, you may not see a great deal of difference between these two
>   alternatives.
>
> By default, find examines symbolic links themselves when it finds them
>   (and, if it later comes across the linked-to file, it will examine
>   that, too).

To my understanding, if I do something like:

```
find -L -iname "*foo*"
```

this will search the current directory recursively and when it encounters a symlink, it follows the link to the original file. If the original file has the name pattern `*foo*`, the former link is reported.

However, this doesn't seem the case. I have

```
main-file
sl-file -> main-file
```

Running the command above `find -L -iname "*main*"` reports

```
./main-file
```

And I was expecting

```
./main-file # because it matches the criterion
./sl-file   # because the file points to matches the criterion
```

That being said, using another test like `-type` works as I am expecting. Say I have this:

```
main-file
dir/sl-file -> ../main-file
```

Running this

```
find dir -type f
```

returns nothing. But this

```
find -L dir -type f
```

reports `dir/sl-file`.

What gives?

I have gone through [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31114/269618) that says a file name isn't a file property. This is something I can't really get my head around.

Comment: I would exactly expect what has happened. Why should `find` find `sl-file` if your searching for `*main*` ? `-L` means that it follow symlinks, not use their real name.

Comment: `find` returns `./main-file` because you have both file and link in the same directory. If you change symlink to point to different directory that won't be searched you will see that `find` won't return anything.

Comment: But I do see that it is not really clear in the docs. `-type` uses the type of the linked file, while `-name` does not. But I think that this is a duplicate to the linked question. I don't think that we can answer any better or anything else than this.

Comment: For me it's clear. I give you example. Let's suppose that you today symlink to file that was last modified 1 year ago and you're trying to find all files modified in less than week, if you use option `-L` `find` won't return that symlink and I you don't use option `-L` `find` will return that symlink. If you specify type you will be searching file with that particular type. `-name` doesn't check file type and it's looking at only name of the file (directory is also file)

Comment: @RoVo, yep. Test `-type` works as I am expecting. I have updated the post with an example.

Maybe you can elaborate why does it work with `-type` but doesn't with `-name`.

Comment: @mrc02_kr, thanks for the provided example. I think you are correct with your example, but the thing is, if you change the test of time to test of name i.e., instead of `-newer` try using `-name`, things won't work as you are talking. Instead, it works in a different way; as I have listed in my original post.

Comment: @joker it works as it should. `find dir -type f` returns nothing because you looking for files but dir/sl-file is link. `find -L dir -type f` reports someting because sl-file points to actual file. If you create another link to dirctory in dir it won't be returned by `find -L dir -type f`

Comment: @mrc02_kr great. Then explain why `find -L dir "*main*"` doesn't report anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnu `find` documentation is not as strict in terminology as the [POSIX one](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html). The latter sheds light and I will refer to it. It doesn't define `-iname` so I will concentrate on `-name`. I assume `-iname` is designed to be like `-name`, only case-insensitive. Therefore I expect all properties of `-name` that have nothing to do with case to apply to `-iname` as well.

These are relevant parts of the POSIX documentation:

> `find [-H|-L] path... [operand_expression...]`
>   The `find` utility shall recursively descend the directory hierarchy from each file specified by `path`, […]. Each `path` operand shall be evaluated unaltered as it was provided, including all trailing <slash> characters; all pathnames for other files encountered in the hierarchy shall consist of the concatenation of the current path operand, a <slash> if the current path operand did not end in one, and the filename relative to the path operand. The relative portion shall contain no dot or dot-dot components, no trailing <slash> characters, and only single <slash> characters between pathname components.

> `-name pattern`
>   The primary shall evaluate as true if the basename of the current pathname matches `pattern` using the pattern matching notation […]

> `-print`
>   […] it shall cause the current pathname to be written to standard output.

And [definitions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html):

> Basename
>   For pathnames containing at least one filename: the final, or only, filename in the pathname. […]

> Filename
>   A sequence of bytes […] used to name a file. The bytes composing the name shall not contain the <NUL> or <slash> characters. […] A filename is sometimes referred to as a "pathname component". […]

> Pathname
>   A string that is used to identify a file. […] It has optional beginning <slash> characters, followed by zero or more filenames separated by <slash> characters.

So `-name` is interested in the final filename in the current pathname; and the current pathname is a string that is used to identify the current file. Used by whom? In this case by `find`. Conceptually a pathname may have nothing to do with names in the filesystem. If `find` uses some string to identify a file then the string is called "pathname" and `-name` uses it.

Invoke `find . -print` or `find -L . -print`. You will see all pathnames used by this particular invocation of `find`. Their final filenames are what `-name` would test if you used `-name`.

---

In your example with `main-file` and `sl-file`, the command is `find -L -iname "*main*"`. There is implicit `-print` at the end, the output you observed is from `-print`. You expected:

> ```
> ./main-file # because it matches the criterion
> ./sl-file   # because the file points to matches the criterion
> ```

But if this was the case, it would mean `-print` gave you `./main-file` and `./sl-file`, so these are the exact pathnames, so `main-file` and `sl-file` are the respective basenames `-name` (or `-iname`) dealt with.

This doesn't fit. Only one of these basenames matches the pattern you used (`*main*`). This is why you got only one result. Specifying `-name "*main*"` (or `-iname "*main*"`) and expecting `./sl-file` to appear is equivalent to expecting `sl-file` to match `*main*`.

It would make *some* sense to expect `./main-file` to appear twice. The premise would be the symlink causes `find` to change the second pathname from `./sl-file` to `./main-file`. Then both pathnames would match `*main*` and both would be printed as `./main-file`. This doesn't happen.

If you'd like this to happen, consider a symlink `bar` pointing to `/etc/fstab` and placed in `/tmp/foo/`. We're in the `foo` directory. What should `find -L .` print (besides `.`)? It seems you'd like this pathname to pass `-name fstab` test, so the basename must be `fstab`. On the other hand, according to the rules the pathname must begin with `./` (because `.` is the provided path) and shall contain no dot-dot components. There is no sane and meaningful pathname that can be used. Now what? Fortunately in such case the tool prints just `./bar`. This is the pathname and it (as a string) carries no connection to `fstab`.

---

Few examples that don't use symlinks but show how `-name` works:

1. ```
   cd /etc && find . -name . 2>/dev/null
   ```

   It finds `.` despite the fact its "real" (specific, in-the-filesystem) name is `etc`. It doesn't find subdirectories despite the fact any directory can be `.` in some circumstances.
2. ```
   cd /etc && find . -name etc 2>/dev/null
   ```

   It finds neither `etc` nor `.`.
3. Create an empty FAT32 filesystem and mount it, `cd` to the mountpoint. The filesystem is case-insensitive and Linux knows it. Create a file named `a` in the filesystem. Experiment like this:

   - ```
     $ find .
     .
     ./a
     ```

     In this case the tool must have obtained `a` from the filesystem at some point.
   - ```
     $ find a
     a
     $ find A
     A
     ```

     In this case the tool uses `a` or `A` taken from its command line argument. The filesystem only confirms such file exists. The filesystem (and the OS) knows this particular file can be referred to as `a` or `A`.
   - ```
     $ find a -name A
     $ find A -name a
     ```

     Nothing! This shows `-name` doesn't care what the filesystem knows about the file. Only the pathname used by `find` matters.

     Somewhat similarly in case of your example: `-iname` doesn't care what the filesystem knows about the symlink and its target. Only the pathname used by `find` matters.

---

To clarify and explicitly state what happens, let us go back to your example with the following directory structure:

```
.
├── main-file
└── sl-file -> main-file
```

`find . -print` or `find -L . -print` prints:

```
.
./main-file
./sl-file
```

These are the pathnames, i.e. *strings* `find` uses to identify the three *files* (directory is also a [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690)). The string `.` comes from the command, the other two were build by examining `.` (now I mean the file, not the string), learning it is of the type directory, deciding if we should descend (in general think of `-prune`, `-maxdepth` if supported), listing its content: `main-file`, `sl-file`.

Note the string `/.sl-file` is built before anything is done to the file identified by it. To do anything with the file, `find` needs the string.

But `-name` or `-print` don't do anything to the file, they don't need its data or metadata. They work with the pathname, the *string*.

When `-name "*main*"` is evaluated for any pathname, the corresponding file or the entire filesystem is completely irrelevant. The only relevant thing is the pathname which is a *string*; more specifically the last component of it, i.e. the basename, also a *string*.

For any given pathname `-name` doesn't care if you used `-L` or if the file is a symlink in the first place, or where it points to, or if it's not broken. It works with the already known *string*.

On the other hand tests like `-type` or `-mtime` need to query the filesystem about the *file* identified by the pathname. String is not enough for them. In case of a symlink `-L` decides if they query about the target of the symlink or about the symlink itself. Still, if there is `-print` involved then it will print the pathname, regardless of what was queried.

In other words:

- without `-L`

  - `./main-file` *string* identifies `./main-file` *file* of type `f`
  - `./sl-file` *string* identifies `./sl-file` *file* of type `l`
- with `-L`

  - `./main-file` *string* identifies `./main-file` *file* of type `f`
  - `./sl-file` *string* also identifies `./main-file` *file* of type `f`

Then you should mind which test or action works with pathnames (strings) and which works with files.

`-name` and `-print` work with pathnames so `find . -name "*main*"` with or without `-L` will only print

```
./main-file
```

`-type` works with files so `find . -type f` will print one pathname:

```
./main-file
```

and `find -L . -type f` will print two pathnames:

```
./main-file
./sl-file
```

Comment: Let me thank you very much for taking the time and effort to put all this together! I really am. I would like very much to it a bit further. Let's take the example you used: `/tmp/foo/bar -> /etc/fstab`, and I'm in `/tmp/foo`, and assume that I created the symlink today. Running `find -mtime 0` returns `./bar`, `find -L -mtime 0` will **NOT** return `/etc/fstab` nor `./bar`. That's expected and is correct. But running `find -L -name fstab` will **NOT** return anything as well! I was expecting `/etc/fstab` to return or `./bar` as it points to a file matching the name.

Comment: Would you please explain why it doesn't apply the name test as it applies the time test?

Comment: So you are saying that only files under the specified pathname are the ones considered?

Comment: Let me re-phrase my question: following a symlink only happens within the pathname(s) specified and links aren't followed if they reside outside any of the passed pathname(s)?

Comment: And let me tell you that your time and effort you put for the discussion is very much appreciated.

Comment: @joker What's inside and what's outside doesn't really matter to the mechanics. Let me expand the answer. It may take few hours so please be patient.

Comment: @joker Done. The new part begins with words "To clarify and explicitly state". Later I may shuffle the parts to create a more logical sequence; I haven't decided yet.

Comment: Wow! That's pretty deep understanding. I don't know how to thank for bearing with me! Alright, so how would one know what tests gets applied on the pathname or the file? Is it anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: @joker The linked POSIX documentation is quite strict. Tests and actions that use pathnames are: `-name`, `-path`, `-print`, `-prune` (when two pathnames identify the same directory and you prune just one, then the other is not automatically pruned). Also `-exec` (i.e. its `{}`). GNU documentation is not that strict but most likely `-iname`, `-ipath`, `-regex` and more. I carefully expect if a test or action can use pathnames *only*, then it won't query the filesystem; unless explicitly stated otherwise. Note GNU `find` supports `-lname`, this cannot use pathnames; test it.

Comment: Okay. Just tried the `lname` and it works as I originally thought `find -L -name` would work. Nice suggestion. I'm feeling better now! In regards to POSIX documentation being strict, well, I had a look at it on `-name` and couldn't develop the same understanding you have. I would still have thought that using `-L` would make `-name` apply the test on the file pointed to by a symlink.

Comment: Reading this `-L Cause the file information and file type evaluated for each symbolic link encountered as a path operand on the command line or encountered during the traversal of a file hierarchy to be those of the file referenced by the link, and not the link itself. If the referenced file does not exist, the file information and type shall be for the link itself.` would leave me with the understanding the `-name` would then act on the original file rather than the symlink even if the original file is out of any of the specified pathname(s).

Comment: @joker Well, I guess some degree of Asperger syndrome is an advantage in this case. :)